# Javascript won't work in Chrome

Tags: 2010, javascript, calendar, chrome

I've a problem with my SharePoint-Javascript.
In IE and FF it works propably fine, but **in Chrome it won't work**.
The script is called on a refresh of the main page and auto adds some users in a calendar.
Here's the code:

```
function _firstTime() {

    SelectRibbonTab('Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar', true);

    setTimeout('_doWireUp();', 2000);

}

function _doWireUp() {
    var weekElem = document.getElementById('Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Scope.WeekGroup-Large');
    if (weekElem) weekElem.onclick = function() {
        setTimeout('_setDefaultResources();', 1000);
        return false;
    };

    var dayElem = document.getElementById('Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Scope.DayGroup-Large');

    if (dayElem) dayElem.onclick = function() {
        setTimeout('_setDefaultResources();', 1000);
        return false;
    };

    _setDefaultResources();
}

function _setDefaultResources() {
    var ret = '---some voodoo with names and sth like that from fiddler ;-) ---';
    var sel = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarSelector.instance().getSelector(1, 'WPQ3');
    sel.selectEntities(ret, true);
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(_firstTime, "sp.ribbon.js");
```

At the Javaconsole in Chrome there's no error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you look at chrome dev tools (F12) what errors do you have?

Comment: as i wrote in my question, I can't see any error

Comment: did you able to step into __firstTime in debug mode?

Comment: This kind of errors could be caused by 1)not well formed block of code 2)different browser implementation of native js functions (like `setTimeout` )

Comment: in ff and ie it works fine...so i think only option 2) is possible..?

Comment: First, you have to make sure you really step into you function(s).

Comment: How should I do that? And why doesn't it work in chrome...

Comment: 1.Open dev-tools (`F12`) 2. open search all input (`ctrl+shift+F`) 3. type `_firstTime` 4. set breakpoint to `SelectRibbonTab...` row 5. reload the page (`F5`)

Comment: Okay..looks like it won't get into the function. - I set a breakpoint to "Select RibbonTab.." but after a reload, nothin changes or stops...the page just reloads and the calendar won't show the people..

Comment: It means, that due to difference in browsers, the execution doesn't even step into that code. Look for a problem before (it could be anything , like not closed HTML tag, missing `;` symbol, etc).